# Stretching the layout of an app to fit the screen size

Tags: cordova, width, absolute

Please, help a newby. I'm making an app with PhoneGap Build from a .zip of html/css/java. The original layout is based on absolute positioning and the original width is 320 px. The problem is - it doesn't stretch to fit the window width (adapt), but rather leaves white margins. However, when viewed as a mobile website, it adapts perfectly. How do I force the layout to stretch? Should I edit the config.xml (phonegap build) or the androidmanifest.xml? Please, help. I'm really not keen on coding. Thanks!!! Alex.

Answer (score 0):

i would look at the config.xml this sounds like a WindowSize preference https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/